# How can I get the SAP JCo middleware(com.sap.mw.jco.*) APIs in Mac

Tags: macos, jco

I tried to make use of some classes of `com.sap.mw.jco.*`, such as `IRepository` and `JCO`. But my IDE (Intellij) cannot recognize this classes. There are always compilation errors. I tried to add the `libsapjco3.jnilib` to the classpath and also add the vm parameters

```
-Djava.library.path="MY_sapjco_folder"
```

My other JCo packages, `com.sap.conn.*` are recognized correctly.

Could anyone tell me which part I am missing?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SAP JCo 2.x (com.sap.mw.jco.*) is not supported on Mac OS X. While you can add the JAR file to your classpath, the native library (if you use one for another platform) will not load correctly.

You cannot use libsapjco3.jnilib with the SAP JCo 2.x classes - it is for SAP JCo 3.x only (com.sap.conn.*).

The SAP JCo version 2 and version 3 APIs are not compatible - normally you choose to use one or the other. On Mac, you must use version 3.